# Solving a generalised eigenvalue problem

Tags: eigenvalues

I have a generalized eigenvalue problem in the standard form

$\lambda \mathbf{B} \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} $,

resulting from a finite difference discretization of a coupled system of two linear stability equations, so the system is large $(10^5 $ x $10^5)$ and sparse. I know that $\mathbf{B}$ is indefinite, and not symmetric. Since I am interested in the stability of the system, I need to find the first, say ten, eigenvalues with the largest real part.

What it the preferred way to tackle such kind of problem?

I want to solve it using scipy linear algebra package for sparse matrices, but it appears that the eigs function only works when $\mathbf{B}$ is positive definite.

Any help is appreciated.

## Edit

I post a minimal example code that generate my issue. The matrices that I use in the example **are not**  the same I have in my application, but they illustrate the problem.
A working Matlab snippet, producing the correct answer is:

```
A = diag([-5, -4, -3, -2, -1]);
B = diag([1, 1, -1, 1, 1]);
eigs(A, B, 2, 'LR')
```

which produces the correct answer:

```
>> msolution
ans =
    3.0000
   -1.0000
```

An equivalent python version to this problem  is:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse.linalg import eigs

A = np.diag([-5, -4, -3, -2, -1]).astype(np.float64)
B = np.diag([1, 1, -1, 1, 1]).astype(np.float64)
vals, vecs = eigs(A, 2, B, which='LR')

print vals
```

producing the clearly wrong result

```
[ 83.66243085+163.44457559j  83.66243085-163.44457559j]
```

Now, this might look like a bug in Scipy, but the docs explicitly ask for a positive definite matrix $\mathbf{B}$ and the one I have here is not, as the one I have in my application.

Comment: Is $B$ Hermitian? SLEPc has a number of solvers for generalized eigenvalue problems.

Comment: I suspect most of the scipy iterative solvers would have little problem with this.  Have you tried: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html?

Comment: @meawoppl: Yes, I have tried and the output is garbage. Actually, I resorted by making a system call to Matlab and letting its eigs function do the work. This is cumbersome, but Matlab's eigs function appears to work for my case.

Comment: Huh. I am surprised to hear that the sparse solvers do not work for this case.  Can you post example code or a matrix file that produces these wrong results?

Comment: What $\lambda$ are you looking for (largest magnitude, smallest, closest to some particular number,...)? How many eigenvalues? Matrices $A$ and $B$ are nonsingular? If matlab can solve it, I am pretty sure that slepc can solve it too...

Comment: @meawoppl: see the post edit. I just wonder how matlab eigs handles the indefinite matrix $\mathbf{B}$.

Comment: @sebas: see post edit. I look for the fist few eigenvalues with the largest real part, since I am interested in the stability analysis of the system. Both matrices are non-singular. Did not try with slepc, but  I would prefer making my python version work, instead of making a system call to matlab as I am doing now.

Comment: @meawoppl: I'm not at all surprised the sparse nonsymmetric eigensolvers don't work. In my experience, they almost never work reliably. The only real package for solving these problems is ARPACK.

Comment: @victor it is a wrapper for arpack...

Comment: That is what I was about to say: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/arpack.html

Comment: @meawoppl: And I was trying to say that in reality ARPACK often fails.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and spoke with my supervisor. Here is his solution:

### Use -B instead of B:

In my case, matrix B was negative definite (all eigenvalues are negative).

> λ(-B)x=(-A)x

which will give the same result, but -B is positive definite and you can use scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs().
By trying this solution, an error in ARPACK arose for some matrix sizes :

> scipy.sparse.linalg.eigen.arpack.arpack.ArpackError: ARPACK error
>   -9999: Could not build an Arnoldi factorization. IPARAM(5) returns the size of the current Arnoldi factorization. The user is advised to
>   check that enough workspace and array storage has been allocated

I dont know if that error is bound to my particular configuration and code or something else.

### Other alternative for LinearOperator:

In my cases, I didnt have have to matrices A and B but only to the associate LinearOperators. I upgraded the solution of sebas for LinearOperators and it worked well, but it is slower than the first solution as it needs to invert B.

```
from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator

N = your_size

def A_fct(v):
    # write the function you need or just define matrix A
    return np.dot(A, v)
linop_A = LinearOperator( (N,N), matvec = A_fct)

def B_fct(v):
    # write the function you need or just define matrix B
    return np.dot(B, v)
linop_B = LinearOperator( (N, N), matvec = B_fct)

def Binv_A(v):
    retour = linop_A.matvec(v)
    sol, info = scipy.sparse.linalg.gmres(linop_B, retour)
    # or similar to gmres, it calculate inv(B) * A * v
    return sol
linop_Binv_A = LinearOperator( (N, N), matvec = Binv_A)
```

Answer (score 2):

It si very weird. It should be a bug in scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.

Looking at matlab, we see that opening the function with `open eigs`, at line 822-825, they say that

```
% eigs(A,B,k,stringSigma), stringSigma~='SM'
% A*x = lambda*B*x
% => OP = inv(B)*A and use standard inner product.
mode = 2;
```

I have been looking for the same piece of code inside scipy, and it seems that they are doing the same at lines 541-543 in [scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/arpack.py#L541](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.13.0/scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/arpack.py#L541)

```
elif self.mode == 2:
    self.workd[xslice] = self.OPb(self.workd[xslice])
    self.workd[yslice] = self.OPa(self.workd[xslice])
```

where the OPb and OPa have been defined before as the product by $A$ and the inverse of $B$. So I did not found the difference, so it should be a bug.

In Matlab and also in Scipy, they seem to be solving $B^{-1}Ax = \lambda x$. Because of that I was wondering why $B$ is required to be positive definite and not just nonsingular (I think that $B$ must be positive definite for the shift-and-invert algorithm, because there it is used to define a norm). Thus, you can simply modify your code to do the same:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse.linalg import eigs
from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator
from scipy.sparse.linalg import factorized

A = np.diag([-5, -4, -3, -2, -1]).astype(np.float64)
B = np.diag([1, 1, -1, 1, 1]).astype(np.float64)

B_inv = factorized(B);
def mv(v):
    temp = np.dot(A, v)
    return B_inv(temp)

BA = LinearOperator(A.shape, matvec = mv) # BA.matvec(x) is np.dot(inv(B),np.dot(A,x))
vals, vecs = eigs(BA, 2, which='LR')
print vals
```

obtaining the right solution

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py:258: SparseEfficiencyWarning: splu requires CSC matrix format
  warn('splu requires CSC matrix format', SparseEfficiencyWarning)
[ 3.+0.j -1.+0.j]
```

I got a warning because $B$ is not in csr format when performing the sparse LU decomposition (splu) by means of the call to `factorized`, so the factorization function perform the conversion to csr and do the sparse LU. I guess that your matrices already are in csr format, so it will not be a problem.

Here you can also play with an incomplete LU factorization, solving the system with $B$ iteratively, and lots of choices for the reordering of $B$ before the LU factorization to make it efficient.